# Sensitivity, Specificity and Misclassification rate

Tags: classification, sensitivity-specificity

I stumble upon a problem that I'm sure someone else already had.

Assume you have:

- A cohort, composed of 10 healthy subjects and 100 diseased subjects.
- A model M such that M(patient) = diseased. In other words, each patient is classified as diseased.

At this point we can compute:

- Specificity = (TN=100) / (N=100) = 1
- Sensitivity = (TP=0) / (P=10) = 0

Till here everything looks fine: the model poorly represents the reality, and the sensitivity captures this fact.

However, the misclassification rate is 0.09, which usually is not that bad.

This bias comes from the small healthy control sample size.

Is there a way to correct this bias, so that the misclassification rate can represent how inaccurate this model actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bias concerning the misclassification rate, it just measures what it's supposed to measure. As you indicate, misclassification rate or accuracy can be a very misleading measure, especially if the distribution of the classes are unbalanced.

Here are some links about common measures to assess prediction quality:

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~eisner/measures.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Answer (score 1):

Most of your problem comes from the fact that these measures are discontinuous improper accuracy scoring rules.  If you stick with assessing the continuous calibration curve of continuous risk predictions these problems diminish.